# Similar to Jenkins Groovy file. Is there Any file for Bamboo?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, bamboo, bamboo-specs

Im totally new to this Devops field basically  for Jenkins, Groovy file is used  to maintain preparation-build-Deploy, Similarly for Bamboo which script is used?

I got to know bamboo plan is used. But how the plan is generated though any script or any file.

And i have pipeline for Jenkins similarly how it can be done for Bamboo plan.

the groovy file for Jenkins is

```
node {
    stage('Preparation') { // for display purposes
        // Get EDM code from a GitHub repository
        cleanWs()
        checkout scm
        sh "python $WORKSPACE/common/deployment_scripts/abc.py --localFolder $WORKSPACE --env dev"
    }
    stage('Build') {
        // Run the maven build
        sh "mvn clean install -f $WORKSPACE/pom.xml -Dmaven.test.skip=true"
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        //Run the deployment script
        sh "python $WORKSPACE/common/deployment_scripts/ase.py $WORKSPACE lm-edm-builds-ndev ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} dev"
        sh "python $WORKSPACE/common/deployment_scripts/qwert.py --JsonParameterFile $WORKSPACE/common/deployment_scripts/my_properties.json --BuildVersion ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} --WorkSpace $WORKSPACE --environment dev"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bamboo, you can do so with Bamboo Specs. The Bamboo Specs allows you to define Bamboo configuration as code, and have corresponding plans/deployments created or updated automatically in Bamboo. Read more about the [Bamboo Specs here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bamboo+Specs).

Bamboo Specs recognize two ways of creating plans, with Java or YAML. Select the one that matches your needs best. The syntax for both can be found in their [official reference documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs-docs/7.1.4/).

A sample YAML Specs to define a plan can look like below as detailed in [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-yaml-specs-938844479.html):

```
---
version: 2
plan:
  project-key: MARS
  key: ROCKET
  name: Build the rockets

# List of plan's stages and jobs
stages:
  - Build the rocket stage:
    - Build

#Job definition
Build:
  tasks:
    - script:
        - mkdir -p falcon/red
        - echo wings > falcon/red/wings
        - sleep 1
        - echo 'Built it'
    - test-parser:
        type: junit
        test-results: '**/junit/*.xml' 
  # Job's requirements
  requirements:
     - isRocketFuel
  # Job's artifacts. Artifacts are shared by default.
  artifacts:
     - name: Red rocket built
       pattern: falcon/red/wings
```

You may start with this tutorial for [Creating a simple plan with Bamboo Java Specs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/tutorial-create-a-simple-plan-with-bamboo-java-specs-894743911.html)